# Actionscript 3.0 -change the countdown time from a different frame with a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

i have a countdown timer on one of my frames and also two buttons on another frame . I want to change the timer based on the button clicked . For example : 1 min 3 min . I also have a navigation button which goes to the frame that the timer is placed.Any ideas?

Comment: explain what is countdown timer? In flash we have class of object called `Timer` but I guess you don't talk about that... What you tried already?

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ How about **not** making the Stage itself go to multiple frames? You could easily put timer & buttons on frame 1 of stage and then have another MovieClip (also frame 1) for the would be "stage" content. Then just move within timeline of **only that MC** not the whole Stage itself, when you want to change frames. Use AddChild to add different MCs for a different "scene/view" if necessary. Think of stage only as a 1-frame canvas when making apps (unless this a animated cartoon?)

Comment: Of course i used the timer class  to create my timer (which is placed on frame 5 for) , i do not think there is another way . The thing i am currently trying to do is the following:

Comment: i have main menu option called 'settings' . There i have 2 buttons  when i press one of these and go back to menu , the Start option will display either frame 5 or frame 6 , depending on which button is selected from options. if someone knows a solution i can try it , names can be random , i will adjust my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to propagate such event is by dispatching custom event when the button is clicked, while the frame that has the timer should be listening to that event.

To do so, you can extend the default "Event" class and create your custom event type that the timer frame should addEventListener to it and when the button is pressed, a dispatchEvent of the new event type should be called.

Or you can reuse any of the available events, for example when button1 is pressed, dispatch change event.

Hope this helps, goodluck.

Comment: I am currently looking at dispatch event , so far is close to what i want to do , that was a good one,thanks!